# WebBrowserTask gives error in windows phone 7

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7

Below is code that throws a 404 error code, but works when refreshing the browser:

```
WebBrowserTask wbTask = new WebBrowserTask();                  
wbTask.Uri = new Uri(Uri.EscapeDataString("http://example.com"), UriKind.Absolute);
wbTask.Show();
```

Comment: did you try how it works if you remove: Uri.EscapeDataString ? in your specific static url there is nothing to escape for what I can see.

Comment: yes but i want to open this url "http://survey.questionmarket.com/surv/947607/ai_start.php?site=2&from_ec=0"

Comment: are you adding in the http:// ?

Answer (score 2):

Why you are using Uri.EscapeDataString? Apart from that call the rest of the code is correct and the only reason to come across a 404 would be external to the phone.